# How to make change to a file inside a python-slim container?

Tags: python, docker, editor

I have a `FROM python:3.8-slim-buster` Dockerfile and I want to make a small change to the entrypoint.sh file. Unfortunately it seems there are no editors, neither `vi` or `ed`. Moreover, it is not possible to do `apt-get update` :(

What is the best way to have at least an editor?

Comment: Just a thought: Can you somehow read the file i.e. does it work to `cat` the file to your output? Do you have editing and/or reading rights of the file?

Comment: I can run `apt-get update` just fine

Answer (score 1):

At the very least `apt-get` should be available.

I ended up just doing `apt-get install nano`.

Comment: Note this works but you need to run `apt-get update` first, otherwise in a newly built container you get the error `E: Package 'nano' has no installation candidate` (or at least I did)

Answer (score 0):

If the change is small, `sed` might be an option. For instance,

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' myfile
```

will change all occurences of `foo` by `bar`. The `-i` option means means in-place, so the file will be overwritten.

Here's a nice cheatsheet of sed: https://quickref.me/sed.html#sed-examples

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue with alpine images.

I solved the problem using **Multi-Stage Builds** in the Dockerfile.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/